# Apache2: Deny access for mail.mydomain.com but allow www.mydomain.com, both points same ip

Tags: apache, multiple-domains, virtualhost, httpd.conf

i have a linux mail+http server located throguh Internet at `www.mydomain.com`. Domain was bought at `GoDaddy` so after configuring the server and getting the public ip address i went at GoDaddy's profile to modify the `A` and `MX`entries for my dns zone in order to point them to my server's public ip address. In the `MX` entry i did not placed the ip address but an alias called mail.mydomain.com.

Everything works fine but, as `www.mydomain.com` and `mail.mydomain.com` both are pointing to `x.y.w.z` where i have apache running, when you write `www.mydomain.com` or either `mail.mydomain.com` in the `Internet Browser` my default web page is shown. I would like to tell apache to only show the page if `www.mydomain.com` is written in the url and deny the  access if `mail.mydomain.com` is written. Does anyone knows how sould i do it? Thanks :)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ErrorLog logs/mydomain_com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/mydomain_com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another virtual host for `mail.example.com`, and you can tell Apache to do whatever you want when people go to that host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName mail.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example_com-error_log
    # if you care about hits:
    CustomLog logs/example_com-access_log common
```

Then, if you want to forbid access entirely:

```
    <Directory />
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
```

Or to redirect to your real domain do this instead:

```
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.com/
```

Or you could do something else.

```
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following into your `.htaccess` every visitor coming to your site by means of any domain other than `www.example.com` will be forcedly redirected to the right domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer. Is it possible to achieve what i asked for just through a proper virtualhost configuration set?

Comment: Although technically this works, it's inefficient for a couple reasons: first, mod_rewrite is pretty complex so it's best to avoid using it when you can do without it; also, enabling `.htaccess` files at all [adds several filesystem accesses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) to every request. Besides, it's just weird organization to put a domain-level redirect in a directory context.

Comment: @David, all you say is true, unless you're on a shared hosting where you either way have `.htaccess` enabled.